# Android ListView in a ViewPager below a static layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to create a layout for my activity, but am not sure what the best way to do this is. What I want is a `ViewGroup` on top with some user's information. Then, below that (filling the rest of the vertical space), I have a `ViewPager` that hosts two `ListFragment`s. Both `ListFragment`s contain dynamic feeds relevant to the user.

This works fine, but what I would like to have is something that would scroll the top profile stuff out of view as the `ListFragment`s in the `ViewPager` is scrolled. Attaching HeaderViews to the ListViews don't make sense since I only want the user to swipe between feeds not the feed + static HeaderView, and neither does putting the ViewPager + ListViews in a ScrollView root. Any ideas on a good way of making this layout?